# Creating an JSON Date a la ASP.NET Format

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

There's a great thread here: [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date) that shows how to parse an ASP.NET formatted JSON date:

```
/Date(1224043200000)/
```

... back into an actual JavaScript Date object. However, it doesn't show how to go the other way. So, given a date - how do I go from:

```
new Date() // to /Date(1224043200000)/ ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var d = ['/Date(', new Date().getTime(), ')/'].join('');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var t = new Date();
t.getTime();
```

Comment: Well, that gets you the number of milliseconds corresponding to the Date t.  I suppose you can take that and wrap it in a `/Date(` `)/` string.